# How to declare a variable constant in Python

Tags: python

I want to declare a global variable as a constant. I do not want the user to change the value. I can write a code which does this using a simple if statement.

```
if variable == value:
    pass
else:
    sys.exit(0)
```

But cannot do this for all the variables. Its very difficult and whenever I want to check, I have to write this 4 lines of code (or a nested conditional statement), which only slows the process.

If I have 100 variables, writing `if` statements for all them is not practical.

The scenario is something like, I have a config file from where I am reading more than 100+ variables. I want to allow the end user to change only few variables. If the user by mistake changes or messes up with the config file, the program should terminate.

Is there any possible way in Python to define a variable as constant?

Comment: Why would you have a config file if you're not allowed to change it? That said, it seems like you are trying to verify that the configuration is valid somehow, maybe constants are not the way to go? If you are looking for constants in Python - there are none. The convention is to treat `UPPERCASE` variables as constants and only assign to them once when they are declared - but it's only a convention.

Comment: You can have a look at this: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65207-constants-in-python/?in=user-97991

Comment: If you don't want to user to change any variable, just don't give access.

Comment: i can declare internally. The variable varies as per the version. I know there are no constants in python but wanted to know, why they thavn't really implemented one ... !!!

Comment: Because we're all consenting adults.

Comment: You could make something into a [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) with no `setter`.

Comment: @Bala because it doesn't really make sense in Python. There are immutable objects (so you can't change strings or integers in-place), but an assignment `foo = 'bar'` is just defining a named reference to a string object (see e.g. http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) - there may be multiple names referencing the same object, and re-assigning any of them doesn't change the underlying data.

Comment: "I have a config file from where I am reading more than 100+ variables. I want to allow the end user to change only few variables." So make 2 config files, eg user.cfg and system.cfg. The user can safely change any values in user.cfg, and the stuff that they mustn't touch lives in system.cfg. The contents of system.cfg can be finalized when your script is installed / upgraded. And you can make it so normal users don't have write access to system.cfg; on *nix systems, you can also set a file attribute on it so that even root can't accidentally modify it.

Answer (score -3):

Thanks [Prerak Sola](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498196/how-to-declare-a-variable-constant-in-python#comment45315810_28498196), I was expecting something like this:

```
# Put in const.py...:
class _const:
    class ConstError(TypeError): pass
    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
        if self.__dict__.has_key(name):
            raise self.ConstError, "Can't rebind const(%s)"%name
        self.__dict__[name]=value
import sys
sys.modules[__name__]=_const()

# that's all -- now any client-code can
import const
# and bind an attribute ONCE:
const.magic = 23
# but NOT re-bind it:
const.magic = 88      # raises const.ConstError
# you may also want to add the obvious __delattr__
```

[Reference: [ActiveState Recipes](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65207-constants-in-python/?in=user-97991)]

Comment: As one of the commenters there puts it: *"If the programmer is a moron, you're screwed anyway."* This doesn't actually stop someone from e.g. directly modifying `const.__dict__`.